# Changing from 3 table cells to 2 using media queries

Tags: css, media-queries

I have a table with 3 cells per row one will be always empty and two filled they just will be alternating like info info empty ; empty info info . So I would want to get rid of the empty one in smaller resolutions and I am not sure if there is a way of doing that through media query or should I use JS.

HTML:

```
<div style="display: table;">
    <div class="tr">
        <div class="tc side"></div>
        <div class="tc year">
            2016
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

css:

```
.tr {
    display: table-row;
}
.tc {
    display: table-cell;
}
.side{
    width: 45%;
}
.year{
    text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: does the empty has specific class name ?

Comment: @JacobGoh No, but the empty one is always a div and the non-empty one is an anchor if that helps.

Comment: Add  class to anchor's parent and hide it in lower resolution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can just use media query to set `display:none` to the element, provided that you can CSS select it

```
@media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
  .tr > div.empty {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

this will set `.tr > div.empty` to hidden when screen width is smaller than 767px

Comment: you mean `:empty`?

Comment: But I also need the correct order it is like. |empty div| |decoration| |info| and the row after that is |info| |decoration| |empty div| so I would want to keep info on one side so the decoration will not get messed up.

Comment: @Higeath hmm. i don't fully understand what you're saying. can you create a codepen/jsfiddle for it so that i can help you further ?

Comment: @JacobGoh https://jsfiddle.net/g67per6g/ so I would want after media query to be text 2016 
text 2016

Comment: @JacobGoh yeah but also the 2016 to be aligned with 2016 and text with text thats the problem I don't think is easily solvable with css

Comment: @Higeath like this? https://jsfiddle.net/jacobgoh101/o1uy76u1/2/ i used float left and right

Comment: @Higeath glad to be able to help.

Comment: @JacobGoh Could you check out https://jsfiddle.net/o1uy76u1/3/ I am trying to apply the same media query

Comment: @JacobGoh It seems like float: right makes the div with I I dissapear